# Degree of accuracy to express $T$?

Tags: conventions, measurements, error-analysis, data-analysis

I conducted a pendulum experiment and here are my results:

10T / s:

( The time taken for 10 oscillations measured on a stopwatch that only shows the time to 2 decimal places. Measured in seconds )

For a 50 cm Pendulum. The time takes for 10 oscillations is 14.31 seconds.

I want to find T / s. The time taken for 1 oscillation using the result from above. I can do this by dividing by 10. However to how many significant figures or decimal places should I express the answer? If 10T is measured to 2 decimal places then should T also be measured to 2 decimal places, or should significant figures be used? Furthermore what if I wanted to express $T^2$. To what degree of accuracy would I express this and why.

Edit: Say I measured 14.31 seconds on a stopwatch which only displays values to 2 decimal places. I want to divide this value by 10. Would I express my answer as 1.431 (4sf) or 1.43 and why? Furthermore what if I wanted to square this answer ( Eg. Either 1.431 or 1.43 )? To what degree of accuracy should my answer be?

Comment: The main thing to consider is: How many digits can you **guarantee** taking into account **all** error sources. You don't give estimates for these errors, so we can't tell how many significant digits make sense

Comment: I do not get your question: Your first measurement for 10 oscillations is $T_{10}^{(1)} = 14.31s$ and your fifth measurement reads $T_{10}^{(5)} = 6.15s$. These differ by a factor of two and the decimal places are not relevant at all. You probably should explain in greater detail how the data is generated. Data analysis without the knowledge of how the data is generated is often useless.

Comment: Say I measured 14.31 seconds on a stopwatch which only displays values to 2 decimal places. I want to divide this value by 10. Would I express my answer as 1.431 or 1.43 and why?

Answer (score 0):

Absolute error propagation in calculations is defined by :
$$ \Delta_f = \sum_n \left| \frac{\partial f(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)} {~\partial x_n} \right| \cdot \Delta {x_n} \tag 1$$

Your function is $f=s\cdot t \tag 2$, where $s$ is time scaling constant, namely $s=\frac {1}{10}.$ Putting (2) into (1) gives:

$$ \begin{aligned}
\Delta_f &= \left| \frac{\partial (st)} {~\partial t} \right| \cdot \Delta 
{t} \\&= \left| s \frac{\partial t} {~\partial t} \right| \cdot \Delta 
{t} \\&= s \Delta t   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(3)
\end{aligned}
,$$

Where $\Delta t$ is stopwatch measurement error. Putting scaling constant and stopwatch error into (3), gives your division by 10 resulting error propagation :

$$ \Delta_f = 0.1 \times 0.01s = 0.001s \tag 4$$

So to say resulting error is in the **third** decimal digit,  thus you should format your resulting pendulum period to two decimal places like $T=1.43s$ or $T=1.43(1)s$. Insignificant digits here is marked with `()` parentheses.

Repeat above given error propagation calculation procedure for your another function case $f= s^2\cdot t^2.$